# C++ std::sort custom compare function referencing to another list

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, compare

I am a beginner in C++ and I don't know nor can find the way to address my problem.

I'm trying to sort my vector in an unusual way and fail to do so.

pointsToVisit - list of Point objects that can have their start time and end time.

visitedPoints - list of indexes of Point objects from pointsToVisit vector

I'd like to sort my visitedPoints vector by values of respective Points

```
BeeHive
    std::vector<Point> pointsToVisit;
    std::vector<Route> routes;

Route
    std::vector<int> visitedPoints;
```

My attemp is below:

```
bool BeeHive::isPointsVisitStartPrior (int i, int j) { return (pointsToVisit.at(i).startTime<pointsToVisit.at(j).startTime); }

Route BeeHive::sortRouteByStartTime(int routeIndex){
    Route route2 = Route();
    route2.setStartTime(routes.at(routeIndex).getStartTime());
    route2.setVisitedPoints(routes.at(routeIndex).getVisitedPoints());
    std::sort(route2.getVisitedPoints().begin()+1, route2.getVisitedPoints().end(), isPointsVisitStartPrior);
    evaluateRoute(route2);
    return route2;
}
```

And I get such errors:

```
Error   5   error C3867: 'BeeHive::isPointsVisitStartPrior': function call missing argument list; use '&BeeHive::isPointsVisitStartPrior' to create a pointer to member c:\vrp projekt\vrp\vrp\beehive.cpp  193 1   VRP
Error   6   error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided c:\vrp projekt\vrp\vrp\beehive.cpp  193 1   VRP
```

Example by which I tried to do my work is under this address: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

I'll be thankful for any help received.

---

Might it be possible, that creating bubble sort for my own purposes will substitute std::sort() decently?

Answer (score 1):

isPointsVisitStartPrior is a member function, this cannot be used directly in sort. You have to either use a global function or a function-object.

If you have access to C++ 11 features, you can use a lambda:

```
std::sort(route2.getVisitedPoints().begin()+1, route2.getVisitedPoints().end(), 
[&](int i, int j){ return isPointsVisitStartPrior(i, j);  });
```

You can also make a functor object with an `operator()`, something like

```
class VisitedPointsCompararer {
public:
   VisitedPointsCompararer(const std::vector<Point>& pointsToVisit): pointsToVisit(pointsToVisit) {
   }


   bool operator() (int i, int j) {
      return pointsToVisit.at(i).startTime < pointsToVisit.at(j).startTime;
   }

...

private:
   const std::vector<Point>& pointsToVisit;
}
```

Comment: How do I access the Point then? "pointsToVisit" is undefined then.

Comment: I didn't manage to make Comparator work, but I have a question of other nature. Is the vector sorted with bubble sort algorithm? If so then it would be faster for me to write my own sorting method.

Answer (score 1):

`isPointsVisitStartPrior(int, int)` is a member function. A such, while it looks like it takes two arguments, it really implicitly takes three: it also needs a `BeeHive*` on which to operate (the `this` pointer).

What you need to do is "bind" the `BeeHive*` to the call:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::sort(route2.getVisitedPoints().begin()+1, 
          route2.getVisitedPoints().end(), 
          std::bind(&BeeHive::isPointsVisitStartPrior, this, _1, _2)
     //   ^^^^^^^^^ without C++11, there's also boost::bind
);
```

That will save off `this` as the first argument in the call to the three-argument function, and forward the next two arguments you call it with into the next two slots.

This is logically equivalent to:

```
std::sort(route2.getVisitedPoints().begin()+1, 
          route2.getVisitedPoints().end(), 
          [this](int i, int j){ return isPointsVisitStartPrior(i, j); }
);
```

Though with the lambda, the compiler may be able to inline the call for you.

Comment: I get several errors from file "algorithm" like: '!' : illegal on operands of type 'void'; illegal, right operand has type 'void'; conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal; at "&& !_Pred(*_Pfirst, *(_Pfirst - 1)))" of "while (_First < _Pfirst
  && !_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Pred, *(_Pfirst - 1), *_Pfirst)
  && !_Pred(*_Pfirst, *(_Pfirst - 1)))
  --_Pfirst;"

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: @Stranko What compiler are you using? And can you post the full error?

Comment: @Stranko are there errors above that relating to `std::bind()` not being found or syntax errors for the lambda, depending on which one you're doing?

Comment: I proceeded with lambda and I copied all errors which were present.